# AD error AADSTS90124 when accessing Office 365 SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

From my web api on trying to call the Sharepoint REST API 
I am requesting for an on-behalf of access token:

```
string[] sharepointScopes = { "https://tenantid.sharepoint.com/Files.ReadWrite.All", "https://tenantid.sharepoint.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All" };
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
    result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(sharepointScopes, userAssertion, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0");
}
catch (MsalServiceException e)
{
    if (e.Message.StartsWith("AADSTS50076"))
    {
        string responseMessage = String.Format("{{\"AADError\":\"AADSTS50076\",\"Claims\":{0}}}", e.Claims);
        return SendErrorToClient(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, null, responseMessage);
    }

    if ((e.Message.StartsWith("AADSTS65001"))
        || (e.Message.StartsWith("AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.")))
    {
        return SendErrorToClient(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, e, null);
    }
    else
    {
        throw e;
    }                    
}
```

I am getting error AADSTS90124: Resource 'https://tenantid.sharepoint.com' (Office 365 SharePoint Online) is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint

Comment: What end point does the `/LinkingUri`  refers to?

Comment: LinkingURI is a property of an Item in a Sharepoint List. If I copy and paste the URL in a browser (authenticated with Sharepoint) it returns a result

Comment: As per the AAD documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent I need to specify a tenant guid for accessing a v1.0 endpoint and I was doing that so what am I missing now to be getting the AD error AADSTS90124

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post your code and the error to have a better understanding of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the common endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0) was modified to the tenant endpoint and it worked